# How to choose between higher salary and more immediate benefits like a relocation package?

Tags: salary, relocation, offer

Assuming same location and equally senior and interesting positions

Company A: 65k year, bonus, cycle to work, interesting office with activities and meals, relocation package (from furniture to first month of rent to 4500 euro for the expenses and furniture shipping)

Company B: 80k year, 700 euros in benefits or a company car, more traditional company without an interesting office and cool things happening (quite relevant for an expat), no relocation package

Both companies are very well known and recognised in my field (data). I currently make 40k no benefits so any of them would be an improvement.

Company B would make me sacrifice all my savings to relocate but will be more profitable long term. Company A makes the relocation process easier and I can keep my savings but won't be making that much money.

Are there good reasons to pick one over the other?

EDIT: I have no current goals for the saved money. It was meant to go to my retirement some day or to buy a property but no concrete plans (I'm in my mid 20s)

Comment: Depends on your own specific needs now and in the expected future. I don't think anyone else's answers will help you much.

Comment: Edited with insights about my financial life+

Comment: Doesn't help a lot when the goal of this site is to produce answers that will apply generally, I'm afraid. If you can restructure this as "How can someone compare the value of travel expenses vs. the difference in proposed salary", that might be on topic. However, in your note you cited cultural perks, which are completely outside that equation....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote [some of the best advice I've ever read on salary negotiation](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2012/01/23/salary-negotiation/)

> "salaries are shockingly durable over time"

Company B is $15k more every year. Even if you don't stay at company B that salary will generally follow you to your next job. Your relocation package pays you once. Your salary pays you year after year after year.

Based on current annuity rates, an extra $15k a year income for life would cost ~$200k to buy on the open market*. That's a reasonable guess at what it might be worth to you in the long run.

Your salary is also the basis for pension contributions (which may be employer-matched), bonuses, your credit score, how large a mortgage you can apply for and on what terms, etc. etc.

If you want to pick company A for other reasons then that's cool. But in purely financial terms, given the choice between some kind of one-off payment or more base salary, take the salary every time. It's worth 10x as much to you in the long run.

---

This assumes that both companies are in similar areas with similar tax rates and costs of living. If one of them pays a lot because it's somewhere with much higher costs of living then that negates most of benefit.

---

*Technically, it should be worth much more because you're a lot younger. But your salary also won't last for life, just until you retire, so for the purposes of approximation we can assume they cancel each other out

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be surprised if there was a clawback clause for the relocation package. In other words, if the OP quits/gets fired less than a year into the contract, they may try to get that money back. So the OP really needs to read the final contract (and any employee manual) also before making any kind of decision.